# jQuery - why can't I bind events to elements in a loop?

Tags: javascript, binding, jquery

Here is my code:

```
  var b = $(slipStream.conf.mainVis).find('p#prev');
  b.click(function() {
    slipStream.slideLeft();
        return false;
  });

  b = $(slipStream.conf.mainVis).find('p#next');
  b.click(function() {
    slipStream.slideRight();
        return false;
  });

  b = $(slipStream.conf.controls).find('li img');
  console.log(b);
  for (var l in b) {
        l.click(function() {
              var visIndex = l.index();
              console.log(visIndex);
        });
  };
```

The first two bindings go through, no problem. But I can't loop through a collection and bind something to each member? (the console is telling me that "l.click is not a function.") Is this a limitation of jQuery or is my code off? This seems like it would be the way to do it, though...

Comment: Can you try `$(l).click(function(){ ... });` instead?

Comment: Why don't you use `$.each(b)` or `b.each()` instead? See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/ and http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: @m90 most of the time, if you're doing `$b.each()` you're doing it wrong...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you enumerate over a jQuery object, the values being enumerated are actual DOM nodes and not jQuery wrappers. Therefore, they don't have a `click` method but you can wrap them again to get all the usual functionality.

Of course this is not necessary because you can simply attach a wrapper directly from your initial jQuery instance:

```
$(slipStream.conf.controls).find('li img').click(function() {
    var visIndex = $(this).index();
    console.log(visIndex);
});
```

Comment: the first code above will not work, since it fails to fix the loop variable closure issue.

Comment: @Alnitak: Indeed; fixed it by moving the `index` call out of the event handler. Thank you for spotting.

Comment: no, that still won't fix it - `visIndex` has to be _bound_ to a scope, which your revised code still doesn't do.  The bug is _not_ limited to the loop variable, it applies to _any_ variable change _inside_ the loop but _outside_ of the callback.

Answer (score 2):

This is the classic "loop variables don't work properly in callbacks" bug.

Your variable `l` no longer has the originally supplied value by the time the callback is invoked - it has whatever final value was assigned in the last pass through the loop.

[FWIW, `l` isn't actually a jQuery object, so you have to wrap it - `$(l)` to use it with jQuery]

The *usual* fix to the loop bug is to create an additional closure that *returns* a function *bound* to the current value:

```
for (var l in b) {   // NB: don't use `for ... in ...` on array-like objects!
    var make_cb = function(n) {
         return function() {
              var visIndex = $(n).index();
              console.log(visIndex);
         }
    }
    $(l).click(make_cb(l));
};
```

Fortunately, you don't need a loop at all - you can have jQuery automatically add the callback  to every element by itself:

```
b = $(slipStream.conf.controls).find('li img');
b.click(function() {
    var visIndex = $(this).index();
    console.log(visIndex);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the problem is the `for`loop. `.click` is part of the jQuery, so you must be sure that it's called on element that is wrapper with jQuery.

```
$.each(b, function (index, element) {
   $(element).click(function() {
   });
};
```

Comment: as is `.index()`, since `l` isn't a jQuery collection.

Answer (score 0):

With `each()` you can iterate through a set of jQuery objects:

```
$(slipStream.conf.controls).find('li img').each(function(){
    $(this).click(function() {
        var visIndex = $(this).index();
        console.log(visIndex);
    });
});
```

`$(this)` will match the currently indexed object from the collection.

Comment: `.click()` does an implicit `.each()` on the supplied jQuery object