# Event Handler After FOR Loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, event-handling

**Issue:**

I am unable to properly execute the event handler `$('#vote_' + messagesIds[i]).click(function()`. On clicking the circle, the event handler runs but consequently `error.message` returns `"Object not found"`.

The issue is that `votingOn` is `undefined`, as the value of `this` cannot be acquired.  However, `console.log(this);` displays the `id` and `value` of `'#vote_' + messagesIds[i]` correctly.

The handler makes reference to a circle created above on the third line of `text`.  The event handler is inside of the `function(results)` where `messagesIds` is declared and occurs after the `FOR` loop that amends the HTML to display the button.

Please help.

**Code:**

```
            if (playerStatus == "active"){
                    //GET MESSAGES
                    var Message = Parse.Object.extend("Messages");
                    var query = new Parse.Query(Message);
                    query.equalTo("Game", gameJSON);
                    query.ascending("createdAt");
                    query.find().then(function(results) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                            messagesIds.push(results[i].id);
                            messages.push(results[i].get("Message"));
                            votes.push(results[i].get("Votes"));
                        }
                        console.log(results);
                    //DISPLAY MESSAGES          
                        var text = "<ul>";
                        for (i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                            text += "<li class='messageContainer' id='" + messagesIds[i] + "_container " + "' value='" + messagesIds[i] + "'>";
                            text += "<div class='voteContainer' id='vote_" + messagesIds[i] + "' value='" + messagesIds[i] +"'>" + votes[i] + "</div></div>";
                            text += "</li>";    
                        }
                        text += "</ul>";
                        //Ammend HTML
                        document.getElementById("messagesContainer").innerHTML = text;
                    //VOTING [not working]
                        for (i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                $('#vote_' + messagesIds[i]).on('click',function() {
                                var votingOn = $(this).val();
                            console.log(this);
                                var Messages = Parse.Object.extend("Messages");
                                var query = new Parse.Query(Messages);
                                query.get(votingOn).then(function(results){
                                    results.increment("Votes");
                                    results.save();
                                    console.log("Voted");
                                }, function(error) {
                                    console.log("Voting Error: " + error.message);
                                }
                                })
                        }   
                    })  //end function(results)
                };  //end if player = active clause
```

Comment: Is $(this) an input?

Comment: No console errors, however `error.message` (which reflects Parse.com errors in processing the request) sends back `Voting Error: Object not found`.  This error is in reference to an undefined `votingOn` in `query.get(votingOn)`.

Comment: to bind event dynamically you need to do something like : $('#vote_' + messagesIds[i]).on('click',function() {});

Comment: @SuchitKumar, attempted that, but didn't result in any change.

Comment: see this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9583072/jquery-why-cant-i-bind-events-to-elements-in-a-loop

Comment: @SuchitKumar the event handler is bound, and runs on `'click'` it just doesn't properly reference this value of `this`.

Comment: @SimonStaton No, `this` refers to the above `id` which refers to the 3rd line of var `text`.

Comment: this will be available only if the click event will happen not before that better use: $('#vote_' + messagesIds[i]).val();

Comment: @SuchitKumar then the `messagesIds[i]` is `undefined`.

Comment: then better debug the values of messagesIds[i] and messages and see indexes are proper.

Comment: @SuchitKumar Yes, they're displaying properly when the `messagesContainer` is amended to `text`.